# Get payment history on Paypal API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to find a way of getting a Paypal account holders payment history using the Paypal api. If we have a user's consent (i.e. we've already used the Permissions API to redirect them to Paypal, and they've consented to give us permissions to get details of payments to their account), what's the next step?

I've seen a similar question here which talked about using GetTransactionDetails call, but that seems only to get details for a single transaction. Another answer mentioned the Payment.List method, but didn't give an example of how it's used.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer - I've looked at the documentation and  still have a query about how this works.  We need to get a trasaction history (or payment history) for a paypal account of a third party, with that third partys consent, i.e this is not for any payments that come to any account owned by us. So if a Client gave us consent (via the permissions api?), we could interrogate their payment/transaction history for all payments made to that client within a date range.     Is it definitely possible to do this via transaction api  or other means?   Thanks...

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible with the TransactionSearch API.  You'll need to get permissions from the client (you can use the Permissions Service for this -- you'll need to include `TRANSACTION_SEARCH` in your scope), but once you do, you can run the TransactionSearch call on their behalf and retrieve a list of transactions from their account.  The TransactionSearch API allows you to narrow down the payments by date range, class, status, invoice ID, etc.

Comment: Hi Matt, I had a look at the permissions and merchant sdk's - I used the api sample to grant TRANSACTION_SEARCH permission to a user (I got a RequestToken, TokenSecret etc the response). I then stepped thru the call in the Merchant sdk example and searched for a transcationid that I know exists- it returned "You do not have permissions to search for this transaction". When I searched for the users email, it returned "Receiver email is invalid". I realise this is difficult to analyse, but what do you think I'm missing? Do I need to include the token stuff in the call to TransactionSearch?

Comment: ..continued:   I think that apiUsername, apiPassword and  apiSignature are ok and were populated in the call

Comment: When you're using the Permissions Service, you're supposed to generate a signature using the token and token secret that you got from the GetAccessToken call.  You then put those into the `X-PP-AUTHORIZATION` header in the HTTP request.  This code will help you generate the signature: http://pastebin.com/gMUVR4Fs  **You don't pass your API username, password, or signature in the API call** -- you just pass the `X-PP-AUTHORIZATION` header.

Comment: For example: `X-PP-AUTHORIZATION: signature=aT2urNYdvuRDRnRInvSjk43lRTk=,token=vv0vh8UiyxhPXg0oxkH29I53fRCjz7BzRckSulx3JYru7TOX-oxCVA,timestamp=1331573725`

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks a lot so far, but I'm still not quite there yet - first, I'm using ASP.net, not php, so didn't find the link made as much sense. I'm using the Paypal Permissions SDK, and have got as far as getting a Token and TokenSecret after requesting permissions to to the TransactionSearch.  The various docs out there tell me that I next have to create a Signature, and use that to make the actual call (cont)

Comment: to the Transaction Search. I've seen the function OauthSignature.getAuthHeader being referred to in various places, but this is from the Java SDK, and I can't find an equivalent in the .Net SDK. Apologies for being slow about this!

Comment: You'll need the PayPalPermissionsSDK and PayPalMerchantSDK.  NuGet will help you to download both of these packages.  Once you have both of those, you should be able to plug in your API credentials, token, and token secret into the following example: http://pastebin.com/h1FZnuB0

Comment: Great stuff! Thanks for all your help Matt...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend using the TransactionSearch API.  This will let you get a list of transactions (up to 100 at a time).  You can then use the GetTransactionDetails API to get more information on individual transactions.

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your answer - I've looked at the documentation and  still have a query about how this works.

Comment: This method is now (10/02/2018) deprecated.

Comment: To be fair, "deprecated" just means "we're not making any improvements to it" -- it doesn't mean "it's going away, don't use it".  But yes, TransactionSearch is now deprecated.  [PayPal Sync](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sync/v1/) is the next best alternative.

Comment: @MattCole Have you used the new API? "To use the API on behalf of third parties, you must be part of the PayPal partner network." Isn't that always the case?!

Comment: @KimKern -- eh, not necessarily.  You could be making the call on behalf of yourself (e.g., if you just wanted to get the transaction activity for your own account.)

Comment: @MattCole Perfect, that's exactly what I want. Thank you :-)