# How to get PayPal Payments and Refunds using API

Tags: php, api, paypal, payment

I am trying to retrieve payments and refunds from paypal, using api. It needs to have the option for date range filtering. And with no limit on the number of returned rows.

To be clearer, i'm not looking to make a payment or make a refund using the api, i'm looking to get a list of history transactions of payments received and refunds made on my paypal account, using the api.

Been looking for this option on paypal's documentation for a while now, but can't find anything. i've found GetBalance api call, but it's limited in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) and [GetTransactionDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) should give you what you're after.

Comment: thanks. 

but the function "TransactionSearch " is not good since it's: "Note The maximum number of transactions that can be returned from a TransactionSearch API call is 100."
and this function "GetTransactionDetails" given me the details for a specific transaction.
I am looking to get a list of all transactions between given dates.
and, getting list of all refunds between given dates.
so, going into all the transactions, one-by-one, is not good. And, getting only 100 rows is not good either (i need all).

Do you know of any other way to get the data i'm looking for?

Comment: If there are > 100 results, you'll receive `ACK=SuccessWithWarning`. In this case, provide a narrower date range and resubmit the call.

Comment: thanks PayPal_Robert.
but i'm looking to get ALL the results. and not narrowing down the range. if in a given date range there were 250 transactions, i want to get them all, not just the first 100.

Comment: seems i need to create a function to retrieve 100 rows and then retrieve another 100 and so on... seems like old school, but if that's the way this cookie crumbles...
thanks for your help

Comment: @RonBentata, yes, exactly.  If there are more than 100 you just need to keep calling TransactionSearch with the different ranges in place until get through them all.  Not "old school."  Just something that's in place for performance reasons.

Comment: @AndrewAngell, i think for performance reasons it would have been wiser to set the number-of-rows as an optional parameter, which defaults to 100.
if i want to pull 2400 rows, it is better to do it in one call than in 24 separate calls.

Comment: Not really, though.  When you're generating NVP or XML responses that contain that much data the size of the text ends up being huge and then depending on server settings, timeouts, etc. it may not even work for people.  24 separate calls, though, keeping everything nice and small, would still run very quickly and wouldn't have any issues with timeouts, max POST sizes, etc.  Once you get the loop setup in your script it should run smoothly for you and it won't matter will it?

Comment: @RonBentata How one can be sure that all the transactions were processed if, say, in one day there are 200 of them and in the next day, say, 10 ? Is there an API call to receive at least a list of IDs of all transactions during the period? Or at least total number of them, so later it can be verified.

Comment: @AndreyLebedenko   Are you looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18723298/get-payment-history-on-paypal-api 
Sorry, but it's been some years since I coded with PayPal API...

Comment: @RonBentata exactly that! Using the Merchant SDK I need to prepare a complete history of purchase related payments -- be them payments or refunds. I've found the way to do payments, but not related refunds. I can pull all of them for the period, but I can't find any way to link them together in the API. Probably Merchant SDK wan't designed for such a task.